# button transition toggle back and forth using CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I would like to create a button that toggles back and forth between two states on click.  Currently the first click transitions the button successfully to the second state, but I cannot get the button to transition back to the original state on the second click.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.popup_contact').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.popup_contact {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: #e8eaed;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #424e65 !important;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(0px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.popup_contact:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f00d';
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #424e65;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.popup_contact:hover,
.popup_contact:focus,
.popup_contact:active {
  color: #424e65 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: #e8eaed;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
.popup_contact:focus:before,
.popup_contact:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="popup_contact" style="vertical-align:middle"><span><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `focus` and `active` event is applied:

```
.popup_contact:focus:before,
.popup_contact:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Instead of this you should use:

```
.popup_contact.active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

and you can now toggle it. Cheers!

```js
$('.popup_contact').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.popup_contact {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: #e8eaed;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #424e65 !important;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(0px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.popup_contact:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f00d';
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #424e65;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.popup_contact:hover,
.popup_contact:focus,
.popup_contact:active {
  color: #424e65 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: #e8eaed;
  outline: 0 !important;
}

.popup_contact.active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <button class="popup_contact" style="vertical-align:middle"><span><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: *This is because `focus` and `active` event is applied* No it's because you added the class `.active`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your button to be static until clicked (i.e. no change on hover also), you need to change your CSS clases from:

```
.popup_contact:hover,
.popup_contact:focus,
.popup_contact:active {
  ...
}
.popup_contact:focus:before,
.popup_contact:active:before {
  ...
}
```

To:

```
.popup_contact.active {
  ...
}

.popup_contact.active:before {
  ...
}
```

Currently, you're targeting the various psuedo states, whereas your JavaScript is adding a class.

Answer (score 0):

You need the class `.active` to be in your CSS, see Snippet

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('.popup_contact').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.popup_contact {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  background: #e8eaed;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #424e65 !important;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(0px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  outline: none;
}
.popup_contact:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f00d';
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #424e65;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.popup_contact.active:hover,
.popup_contact.active:focus,
.popup_contact.active:active {
  color: #42465 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: #e8eaed;
}
.popup_contact.active:focus:before,
.popup_contact.active:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>



    <button class="popup_contact" style="vertical-align:middle"><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> </span>
    </button>
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice!  That worked great!  Is there any way to remove the blue outline?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS doesnt have the .active class.

Try add this to your CSS:

```
.active {
border: 5px solid green;
}
```

This should add a green border when active.