# jquery parent() button toggle and form expand

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to toggle a button between two states, on click. The button will also  open a contact form on the first click, once the form is completed the second click will close the form.

My JQ w/ .parent() (On click the form functions fine but there is no button transition from mail icon to close ('x') icon).

```
$("#popup_contact > a.button").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent().toggleClass('focus').toggleClass('active');
        });
```

My JQ - w/o .parent() (On click the button transitions from mail icon to close ('x') icon but the form does not expand into view).

```
 $("#popup_contact > a.button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('focus').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

I am very new to Java/Jquery, so if more information is needed to understand the problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to enclose the form with a div+class to make it more easy to manage on jQuery, plus form height/width edit normally translates into errors.

I mean something like this:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="close-form"> X </div>
  <form>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the script looking something like this:

```
 $(".close-form").click(function(e){
   $(this).parent('.form-wrapper').toggleClass('focus').toggleClass('active');
 });
```

If you need more help I can answer your questions.

Comment: i am receiving a syntax error and nothing functions (button and form)  i added the JQ like this:                                                              $("#popup_contact > a.button").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent('#popup_contact .popup_contact_wrapper').toggleClass('focus').toggleClass('active');
        });

Comment: I will make jsfiddle for you with your functionality, one moment.

Comment: I appreciate your help and see what you've done, but I am trying to use the same button to open and close the form.  the user will first see a mail icon -> click -> contact form opens and button transitions to an 'x' icon (accomplished via CSS transitions) -> when user is finished with the form -> click 'x' icon -> form closes and button returns back to mail icon.  See this thread for button function:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591157/button-transition-toggle-back-and-forth-using-css-or-js